# how to update to t3 with cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an t1 instance on elastic beanstalk.Now I want to upgrade to t3 so I just update the value but I got an error:

```
Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 't3.micro' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'InstanceType'): Value is not one of the allowed values: 
[t2.micro, t2.small, t2.medium, t2.large, t2.xlarge, t2.2xlarge, m3.medium, 
m3.large, m3.xlarge, m3.2xlarge, c3.large, c3.xlarge, c3.2xlarge, c3.4xlarge, 
c3.8xlarge, t1.micro, t2.nano, m1.small, m1.medium, m1.large, m1.xlarge, 
c1.medium, c1.xlarge, c4.large, c4.xlarge, c4.2xlarge, c4.4xlarge, c4.8xlarge, 
c5.large, c5.xlarge, c5.2xlarge, c5.4xlarge, c5.9xlarge, c5.18xlarge, m2.xlarge, 
m2.2xlarge, m2.4xlarge, r4.large, r4.xlarge, r4.2xlarge, r4.4xlarge, r4.8xlarge,
r4.16xlarge, m4.large, m4.xlarge, m4.2xlarge, m4.4xlarge, m4.10xlarge, m4.16xlarge, 
cc2.8xlarge, hi1.4xlarge, hs1.8xlarge, cr1.8xlarge, g2.2xlarge, g2.8xlarge, p2.xlarge, 
p2.8xlarge, p2.16xlarge, p3.2xlarge, p3.8xlarge, p3.16xlarge, i2.xlarge, i2.2xlarge, 
i2.4xlarge, i2.8xlarge, i3.large, i3.xlarge, i3.2xlarge, i3.4xlarge, 
i3.8xlarge, i3.16xlarge, r3.large, r3.xlar
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the latest version of the platform (Node, PHP, Java, etc). This instance type is really new and it will be probably offered on the latest versions of the platforms.

If you have an older version, before update the platform, I recommend you [to clone the environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.clone.html) first, make the update and test your application has not broken due to new versions of the software components. After confirming everything is Ok, you can modify the platform version on the template.